# Bootstrap google maps not showing less than 960px

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I know there are quite a few questions posted on this topic already but despite having tried other suggestions, my issue still persists. When I resize the browser to be less than 960px, the google map no longer displays. When I check the elements in dev tools, I see the height css for my map div id is not being applied. I tried changing it to 100px as recommended in another post but issue persists. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/we4321/8hs3nLe5/

```
 #map-canvas {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  height:calc(100% - 0px);
  }
```

Comment: I was able to resolve. I had to add col-xs-3, col-sm-3 classes to handle when browser reached that breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Use embed-responsive for your map-canvas:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
 <div id="map-canvas" class="embed-responsive-item"></div><p>
</div>
```